# didupdatelocation not called repetedly in ios 7.1

Tags: ios, cllocationmanager

I am developing an application with location and getting coordinates successfully then i am calling the webservice to store the coordinates, but when i use ios 7.1 device then didupdatelocation method is not called repeadly. Here is my code

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
    {
        self.locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=NO;

        self.locationManager.delegate = self;
        self.locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        [self.locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
    }
```

and this

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D center;

        center.latitude = [[locations objectAtIndex:([locations count]-1)] coordinate].latitude;
        center.longitude = [[locations objectAtIndex:([locations count]-1)] coordinate].longitude;

        _point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];
        _point.coordinate = center;

        if(appDelegate.strVehicleType!=nil)
        {
            [self checkInternet];
        }

        NSLog(@"Changed");

        [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
    else
    {
        CLLocationCoordinate2D center;

        center.latitude = [[locations objectAtIndex:([locations     count]-1)] coordinate].latitude;
        center.longitude = [[locations objectAtIndex:([locations     count]-1)] coordinate].longitude;

        _point = [[MKPointAnnotation alloc] init];

        _point.coordinate = center;

        if(appDelegate.strVehicleType!=nil)
        {
            [self checkInternet];
        }

        NSLog(@"Location Changed in Background")
        ;
        [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
    }
}
```

I have tried above code the location updates repetedly in ios 6 and ios 7 but not updating in 7.1, So please anyone have idea where is the issue? or is their any different method to use.

Thanx in advance.

Comment: Check out my solution for iOS 7 and above. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946881/background-location-services-not-working-in-ios-7/21966662#21966662 There is a blog post and also full solution from Github.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using simulator for test than please reset simulator.
if you are using device then delete app from it.

Add `#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>` Framework in .h file

add delegate `CLLocationManagerDelegate` in .h file

In viewDidload put below code

```
if ([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled])
{
    locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=YES;

    locationManager.delegate = self;
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy=kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}
```

======
Then

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{
    if (UIApplication.sharedApplication.applicationState == UIApplicationStateActive)
    {

        NSLog(@"Active");

    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Non Active");
    }
}
```

run app, it will give you alert 'Appname' Would like to use your current location", press "Ok"

If you are using simulator for test then please take below step:

From toolBar of Simulator
Debug > Location > Apple

After taking these steps simulator change location and method will call.

Comment: no @Viky same result didupdatelocations is not called.

Comment: i am using device with ios 7.1

Comment: I have edited my answer Please take this step if you are using simulator

Comment: this code works like charm in ios 6 and ios 7 but not working in ios7.1, also used different methods to start location update, given the distance filter, but still same issue...

Comment: I am testing in iOS 7.1 and its working. Please try your code i just copy your code and its working fine...

Comment: Please try after reset your simulator.

Comment: After reset simulator run app than app will give you alert "'Appname' Would like to use your current location" than press "Ok" than follow steps :From toolBar of Simulator Debug > Location > Apple

Comment: can u plz post the code? because i have removed to call webservice just pointed debug on didupdatelocations but still not getting the call?

Comment: i have used your code it only called 4 times in my iPod.

Comment: The app is in the active state after some time it's called didfailwith error delegate method, but now not calling just stopped called didupdatelocations...

Comment: Change code From self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=NO; To self.locationManager.pausesLocationUpdatesAutomatically=YES;

Comment: also done that but still same result... i think there is something lacking from my side, because at your side it's working...

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because the Background App Refresh is OFF in your Device So...

Go to **General > "Background App Refresh" > Turn ON.**

and **General > "Background App Refresh" > your app > Turn ON.**

Solve your Problem

Comment: the background app refresh is on i have turned it off and back turned it into on & then tested but still same result..

Comment: App kill and again resart

Comment: and remove this line   [_locationManager stopUpdatingLocation]; from your code