# Activate application after some duration in ios 7

Tags: ios, ios7, background, location

I am working on an application which periodically reads location data, whether in foreground or background. Currently I'm using implementation given by @Ricky from this link: [Background Location Services not working in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946881/background-location-services-not-working-in-ios-7/21966662#21966662) to read location data periodically. The problem is, if user closes application from background by double tapping home button, I am unable to restart my service automatically.

I even tried "Significant location change" service by calling,
    [locationManager startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges];
in ApplicationDidEnterBackground. But no success.

Is there any other way in ios 7, using which, the application can be activated automatically?

Comment: No you can't open activate the application once it killed. You should tap the application or open some url which points to your application.

Comment: @jailani I read that it is possible in 7.1 and above. But didn't found any sample relating it. do you know the method for 7.1?

Comment: Can you please send that link?

Comment: Sorry I didn't read it in any official document but in comments section of different links, some quick links I can found now are, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946881/background-location-services-not-working-in-ios-7/21966662#21966662 and http://mobileoop.com/background-location-update-programming-for-ios-7

Comment: or may be it's just a myth! ;)

Comment: Life360 is an application in which, I guess, they are using this kind of functionality.

Comment: From that answers, It says about start and restart the location manager only not launching the application.