# terminating an app from didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiapplicationdelegate

So, I have an app that monitors significant location changes. I want to only record changes at most every 2 hours. The other times, I really don't want my app to startup at all. Does anyone know if I can terminate my app from within

`- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions`

Will returning "False" cause my app not to be loaded (from the docs it seems that is only if it is trying to handle a URL).

Comment: how do you monitor location changes?

Comment: The return value of this method is only used to determine whether the app can handle a URL resource, if one is specified in the launchOptions dictionary.

Comment: with a CLLocationManager call to startMonitoringSignificantLocationChanges

Answer (score 2):

You should not terminate the app as it lead to rejection by apple.As [docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html) say

> There is no API provided for gracefully terminating an iOS application.

You can show pop up to user for appropriate message.During development or testing you can call `abort()`.But you should not ship your app with any of terminate api as apple strongly discourage this.

Answer (score 1):

you can try exit(0); but Let me warn you apple may reject your app if you terminate your app willingly, what would be better is to show a dialogue box containing the reason and asking the user to close the app on thier own.

Comment: Apple has no problem with manual force close using exit(0), All they need is a proper explanation. I saw some post who had approved app with that code.

Answer (score 0):

You really should not terminate your application, but should prompt the user that there's nothing to show at the moment and have them go to the home screen.

However, if you really want to, you can use `abort()`.

From [Apple's Developer Library](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1561/_index.html) (emphasis added):

> In iOS, the user presses the Home button to close applications. Should your application have conditions in which it cannot provide its intended function, the recommended approach is to display an alert for the user that indicates the nature of the problem and possible actions the user could take — turning on WiFi, enabling Location Services, etc. Allow the user to terminate the application at their own discretion.
>   [...]
>
> If **during development or testing** it is necessary to terminate your application, the `abort` function, or `assert` macro is recommended.

Comment: i don't think you are getting my question... this is when the app is in the background during the location update... there is no UI at this point, but i don't want to load all the other stuff necessary to run the app in the background

Comment: This question may have already been answered: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/21966662/2510167](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21966662/2510167).  At any rate, iOS doesn't run any of the code in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` when you execute in the background.

Comment: For anyone reading this, @jonjesbuzz's comment is incorrect, `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` will be called in the background in some situations, e.g. delivering a background location update.