# Worklight iOS Geofence Native API stops working in background after few mins

Tags: ios, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-geolocation

I am developing geofencing application using worklight ios native apis.

I am using worklight 6.1 and testing application on my iPhone4 with ios 7.1.2.

Below is the native ios code i have written to create geofence.

```
WLGeoAcquisitionPolicy* geoPolicy = [WLGeoAcquisitionPolicy getLiveTrackingProfile];

id<WLDevice> wlDevice = [[WLClient sharedInstance] getWLDevice];

// now, set-up configuration for ongoing acquisition
WLLocationServicesConfiguration* config = [[WLLocationServicesConfiguration alloc] init];

// 1. Acquisition Policy (same one that is used for the one-time acquisition)
WLAcquisitionPolicy* policy = [[WLAcquisitionPolicy alloc] init];
[policy setGeoPolicy: geoPolicy];

[config setPolicy:policy];

WLTriggersConfiguration* triggers = [[WLTriggersConfiguration alloc] init];

WLGeoEnterTrigger *wlTypeAEnterRegionTrigger = [[WLGeoEnterTrigger alloc] init];

[wlTypeAEnterRegionTrigger setArea:[[WLCircle alloc] initWithCenter:[[WLCoordinate alloc] initWithLatitude:19.5687f longitude:72.8748f] radius:500.0f]];

[wlTypeAEnterRegionTrigger setConfidenceLevel:HIGH];

[wlTypeAEnterRegionTrigger setCallback:[WLCallbackFactory createTriggerCallback:^(id<WLDeviceContext> deviceContext) {
                        @try
                        {

                            [[triggers getGeoTriggers] removeObjectForKey:"Offer1"];

                            [self showLocationNotificationWithOfferID:"Offer1" andDescription:@"offer description"];

                        }
                        @catch (NSException *exception)
                        {
                            NSLog(@"Error Occured in LBSManager::enterTriggerCallBack : %@",[exception description]);
                        }
                    }]];

                    [[triggers getGeoTriggers] setObject:wlTypeAEnterRegionTrigger forKey:"Offer1"];

[config setTriggers:triggers];

[wlDevice startAcquisition:config];
```

After creating `WLGeoEnterTrigger` location service icon appears in status bar and after that i am putting application in background after few minutes location service icon disappears.

When i put application in foreground and i get this `wlLocationServicesConfiguration` as nil.

```
WLLocationServicesConfiguration *wlLocationServicesConfiguration = [[[WLClient  sharedInstance] getWLDevice] getLocationServicesConfig];
```

I have also added neccessary BackgroundModes still it does not work.

even if i kill the app i get this `wlLocationServicesConfiguration` as nil.

```
WLLocationServicesConfiguration *wlLocationServicesConfiguration = [[[WLClient  sharedInstance] getWLDevice] getLocationServicesConfig];
```

Comment: Using the provided native sample project, we cannot recreate the disappearing location icon you are experiencing. 1) Can you provide a working sample to debug? 2) This may happen if you have removed all triggers. In this case the location service will stop, explaining the resultin nil.

Comment: Waiting to hear from you about this question.

Comment: No @IdanAdar we are not removing any triggers when app moves to background.Most of the code for sample is shared here in question already still i will try to provide you a working sample if my client permits.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the answer to the following question may explain it: [MobileFirst 6.3 - Enabling location trigger in Background in Hybrid Applications for iOS environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28962176/mobilefirst-6-3-enabling-location-trigger-in-background-in-hybrid-applications)

The answer by Carmel is as follows:

> First see this for how to set permissions to run location services in
>   the background:
>   [Background Location Services not working in iOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18946881/background-location-services-not-working-in-ios-7)
>
> There is limitations in Ios. After couple of minutes of running in the
>   background without any location update the app get suspend and all the
>   location update will be received once the user bring the app back to
>   life.